# Replacing Bootstrap files not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I've tried replacing Bootsrap.css and Bootsrap.css.min files to apply a theme and even though it will show up in the design panel for each of my pages, the theme will not apply itself. Is there anything in the Master I need to edit? I am using Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you add more details? Perhaps some code that it'll be easier to understand what exactly you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, turns out the master page was overwriting part of it